# Python program to convert miliseconds to hours,minutes and seconds logical error

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am learning python and I have a program that converts miliseconds to hours,minutes and seconds. I am getting an incorrect output that's different from the sample run. Here is the question and sample run
[Question description and sample run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwUx.png)

I have come up with the code below

```
def convertMillis(millis):
  seconds=(millis/1000)%60
  minutes=(millis/(1000*60))%60
  hours=(millis/(1000*60*60))%24

return hours,minutes,seconds 

def main():
  millis=int(input("Enter time in milliseconds "))
  con_hour,con_min,con_sec = convertMillis (millis)
  print("%d:%d:%d" % (con_hour, con_min, con_sec))

main()
```

When I test the program with the values in the sample run that is convertMillis(5500),convertMillis(100000) I get the correct values but when I try this convertMillis(555550000) I get 10:19:10 instead of 154:19:10

Here is my output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFmtE.png)

Comment: Just a simple idea: 154 hours is 10 hours plus six full days....

Comment: ^Yep, you do not want to truncate hours by taking modulo 24, if you're not going to account for days separately.

Comment: @muru kindly assist me do it with a code snippet. I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating seconds, `% 60` is used so that the number of seconds is what's left after accounting for a whole number of minutes (so if we had 140 seconds total, 120 would be accounted for in 2 minutes). Similarly, for minutes, `% 60` is so that the number of minutes is what's left after accounting for a whole number of hours (so if we had 450 minutes, 30 minutes would be left after accounting for 7 hours).

But for the final step of calculating hours, we want the total number of hours, not what's left after accounting for the number of days. So we just want:

```
hours = (millis // (1000 * 60 * 60))
```

without the `% 24`.

Note that [`/` in Python 3 is not integer division](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html?highlight=division#division). You need `//` for that. Or you'll get floating point numbers:

```
>>> 421//60
7
>>> 421/60
7.016666666666667
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @muru. It worked like a charm. you are a darling